# Excel calculates wrong

Tags: excel-formula

I have a value `(B3*40*52)` where `B3 == $16.09`. If I calculate this value manually `(16.09*40*52)`, my answer is `$33,467.20`. If I use the value `B3` in a formula `=B3*40*52`, my answer is `$33,476.35`. The cells are formatted to Accounting. What gives?

I've tried using `SUMPRODUCT()`, `ROUND()`, `SUMPRODUCT(ROUND())`, `SUM()`...etc.

```
=SUM(B3*40*52), =SUMPRODUCT(B3*40*52), =ROUND(B3*40*52), =SUMPRODUCT(ROUND(B3*40*52))...
```

I expect `$33,467.20`, but instead, excel calculates `$33,476.35`. If the answer was within a few cents, it wouldn't be a big deal, but this is a $9 difference.[excel formulas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmabz.png)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The value in cell B3 might not be exactly 16.09. If you divide 33476.35 by 40*52 you get 16.094399...
So if you set the cells to accounting with only two digits, Excel will round the display to 16.09. So actually Excel is right because it uses the full precision and your calculation just uses a rounded value.

Comment: The value is exactly 16.09. I have a wage progression chart where I reference the exact hourly wages and convert them into salaries.

Comment: @BrandonYarosz: Can you enter 16.09 explicitly again in cell B3 or another number to be sure your formula works as intended? Can you provide the Excel sheet for us to inspect? Otherwise there are just too many possibilities where something hidden might be going on.

Comment: Okay so I'm new to this site, how can I upload the worksheet?

Comment: Actually, you are correct, now that I reviewed the formula. I have an increase of ((0.03* B2) +.15)+ B2). I apologize, I thought I had an exact value. Is there a way to increase the precision on formula examples such as this?

Comment: @BrandonYarosz: you need to increase the number of decimals displayed for the respective cells. Or you can modify the formulas to truncate / round the result to a pre-decided number of decimals.

Comment: Okay I ended up rounding the referenced formula using, =ROUND(((B2*0.03)+0.15)+B2,2). All I had to do from there was drag the formula across the sheet and VOILA! everything works as I had intended. Thank you for help everyone!